# Is it possible to get axis lines to cross with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart built using highcharts and for purely aesthetic reasons would like the grid lines to cross at 0 and continue slight into the negative as in the image below. How can I achieve this?

[image: small image showing axis intersection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of properties to accomplish this

See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/AzFME/3/

Use some or all of these properties to enable:

```
   xAxis: {
        offset: -15,
        min:-1,
        showFirstLabel:false,
        startOnTick:false,
```

- set the axis offset property to a negative value
- set the axis min to a negative (or low) value
- set showFirstLabel and startOnTick to false

adjust values as needed.